# Where can I get a pretty dress?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have downloaded the Valentine's Day Massacre add-on, but I still can't buy dresses for my female character.
Is there a fix for this, or do I just have to live with it?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you will just have to **live with it**. Clearly stated in the [Rockstar Games website](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52188/GTA-Online-Valentine-s-Day-Massacre-Special-Is-Now-Available):

> These items are all available to purchase in GTA Online right now
>   until the end of February - and once acquired they're yours to keep in
>   your inventory for good.

I am supposing that you did not attempt to buy the dresses BEFORE February here, as you do not specify. If you did, please inform me.